# HTML, Canvas Path2D alternative.

Tags: canvas, drawing, mobile-safari

I draw some graphics on my website using Path2d. Nothing complicated, just two triangles. But MobileSafari fails to create Path2D() object.

Is there any workaround for it ? or any library to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path2D is not yet supported in all browsers. You may be able to use a polyfill such as **[this one](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill)** to get around this.